# Howto: c++ Function Pointer with default values

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have:

```
typedef void (*RespExtractor) (const cv::Mat & image, cv::Mat & resp);

virtual void predict_image(const cv::Mat & src,
            cv::Mat & img_detect,cv::Size patch_size,
            RespExtractor );

void create_hough_features(const cv::Mat & image, cv::Mat & resp, FeatureParams & params =   FeatureParams() );
```

How would i define the RespExtractor to accept a function with default parameters, such i can call:

```
predict_image(im_in,im_out,create_hough_features);
```

I tried following, with no succes:

```
typedef void (*RespExtractor) (const cv::Mat & image, cv::Mat & resp,FeatureParams params, FeatureParams());
```

Comment: Default parameters aren't part of the function signature...

Comment: So i cant achieve what i want ?

Comment: Not this way. Consider std::function instead

Comment: `FeatureParams & params = FeatureParams()` will lead to an error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Function pointers themselves can't have default values. You'll either have to wrap the call via the function pointer in a function that does have default parameters (this could even be a small class that wraps the function pointer and has an `operator()` with default paremeters), or have different function pointers for the different overloads of your functions.

Comment: Good suggestion about the class example.

Comment: I created a class wrapper, is it possible to make an operator abstract in the base class.

Comment: @s093294: it is, but I would advise against it. I would advise using a regular function if it needs be virtual... the question of course would be, why should it be virtual, since it already dispatches to a function pointer ?

Comment: Instead of function pointers i decided to create a simple class with operator() overload and then i just inhered from this class instead and pass that as a parameter instead of a function pointer. i made a virtual method generate, which the operator() calls. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Default parameters aren't part of the function signature, so you can't do this directly.

However, you could define a wrapper function for `create_hough_features`, or just a second overload that only takes two arguments:

```
void create_hough_features(const cv::Mat & image, cv::Mat & resp, FeatureParams & params) {
    // blah
}

void create_hough_features(const cv::Mat & image, cv::Mat & resp) {
    create_hough_features(image, resp, DefaultParams());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did typedef void (*RespExtractor) (const cv::Mat & image, cv::Mat & resp,FeatureParams &); and predict_image(im_in,im_out,create_hough_features,FeatureParams & par=DefaultParams() );

Comment: Vent with the suggestion of @pmjordan