# passing std::stoi in std::transform

Tags: c++11

I have a `vector` of `strings` and an empty `vector` of `int`:

```
vector<string> ints_as_strings;
vector<int>    ints_as_ints;
```

Goal is to transform the former into the latter.

`std::transform` with a lambda works:

```
std::transform(ints_as_strings.begin(),
               ints_as_strings.end(),
               back_inserter(ints_as_ints),
               [](const string& s) {return std::stoi(s);});
```

However I just want to use `std::stoi`.

Passing the address of my `mystoi` function works:

```
int mystoi(string s) {return stoi(s);}

std::transform(ints_as_strings.begin(),
               ints_as_strings.end(),
               back_inserter(ints_as_ints),
               &mystoi);
```

However, directly passing the address of `std::stoi` doesn't work.
Is this on account of the [extra parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (for which, however, default values are provided)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use lambdas? What problems they create?

Comment: I am trying to understand why passing the address of my own function works whereas passing the address of `std::stoi` doesn't.

Comment: `std::stoi` has two parameters with default values:
`int stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );`
---
`std::transform` wants UnaryOperation (one parameter)
`template< class InputIt, class OutputIt, class UnaryOperation >
OutputIt transform( InputIt first1, InputIt last1, OutputIt d_first,
                    UnaryOperation unary_op );`

Comment: Please, read [Function Pointer with default values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760672/howto-c-function-pointer-with-default-values)