# How to convert a captureless lambda with a default parameter to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, c++20, default-parameters

I am trying to store a captureless lambda that has a default parameter to a function pointer.  I have the below code working for a lambda with a default argument

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
decltype([](int a = 10) {  std::cout << a << std::endl;}) my_lambda {};

my_lambda();
my_lambda(21);
return 0;
}
```

I have also managed to convert to a function pointer

```
#include <iostream>
using command_t = bool (*)(int);
int main()
{
decltype([](int a = 10) {  std::cout << a << std::endl; return true;}) my_lambda {};
command_t testFunction(my_lambda);
//testFunction();
testFunction(21);
return 0;
}
```

But I lose the default parameter as I cannot uncomment the testFunction() and run it as the compiler tells me that it is expecting a parameter.  How can I combine these two concepts and convert these lambdas to a function pointer and keep the default parameter?  I am using gcc 10.2.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that a default value isn't part of a function signature, so... I don't think it's possible have a function pointer with a default argument.

Comment: max66 is correct. It is also explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760672/howto-c-function-pointer-with-default-values

Comment: @drel: Given the OP is aware of everything but "How to keep default parameter in a function pointer?" and the answer to that ("You can't") is in that question, I'm closing as a duplicate.

Comment: It is a bit of a workaround.  But I was able to create a struct that has a function pointer member and then by overloading the call operator with a default parameter, I was able to keep the default parameter with the use of a function pointer.  Now instead of having a vector or map of function pointers.  I have a container of my struct and just use the call operator.

Comment: "But I was able to create a struct that has a function pointer member and then by overloading the call operator with a default parameter" - So you have reinvented the lambdas.