# Construct a class that have default arguments with given arguments

Tags: c++, class, parameters, arguments, c++17

Example I have some random class, which constructor have some default arguments. And I have a function to construct there class with some given arguments, and I need somehow to check if I can construct there class with those given arguments

```
class someRandomClass
{
public:
    someRandomClass(int a = 0, float b = 0.f, double c = 0.0, const char* d = "") {}
    // any argument you can think of
};

template<typename Cls, typename... Ts>
void constructClass(Ts... args) {
    // something to check
    if (constructable(Cls, Ts...))
        Cls myClass(args...);
}
```

Are there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Does [Function Pointer with default values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9760710/7582247) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) traits might help (And you might get rid of `fake_constructor` :-) ):

```
template<typename Cls, typename... Ts>
// requires(std::is_constructible_v<Cls, Ts&&...>) // C++20,
                                                  // or SFINAE for previous version
void callClassConstructor(Ts&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<Cls, Ts&&...>)
    {
        Cls myClass(std::foward<Ts>(args)...);
        // ....
    }
}
```